# Google Sheet auto-refresh calculated fields

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has 20 columns. Most of these columns are calculated fields. Whenever I open the sheet, even the sheet hasn't been touched at all since I last opened it, it refreshes most of the columns automatically. How do I prevent this from happening? The sheet is huge so it takes forever to refresh these fields. I don't understand why it does this even when the data hasn't changed at all. Any help is appreciated.

I am hoping the sheet is only refreshed when I update the base data that is used to populate the calculated fields.

Comment: I think that your best bets are: 01 - Set calculation to be on change in the file's settings; 2 - Limit the ranges in the formulas, in case they don't having a start and end row to calculate; 03 - Eliminate any blank cells (Columns and Rows), since it doesn iterate through these looking for functions to execute/calculate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent formulas from recalculating when their source data changes. Formulas automatically recalculate when they detect a change in their parameters, and when there is a lot of data and many interconnections, you get a cascading effect.

There are many things that may slow down a spreadsheet. If you had a magic way to prevent recalculation, that would only treat the symptoms but not the disease. To improve spreadsheet performance, see these [optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339).